# Find the Vertical Asymptotes for the function

Tags: calculus, functions

Find the vertical asymptotes for the function $f(x)=\frac {3x^2-18x}{x^2+2x-8}$

I'm pretty sure you factor both sides, but I'm not sure what happens after, how to solve for *x*.

Please Help!!

Comment: Have you factorised the numerator and the denominator?

Comment: The denominator is $(x+4)(x-2)$ and is $0$ at $-4$ and $2$. The numerator isn't. So the thing blows "up" as we approach $-4$ and as we approach $2$,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$f(x)=\frac {3x^2-18x}{x^2+2x-8} = \frac{3x(x-6)}{(x + 4)(x - 2)}$$

Now, where is the denominator not defined?

- When it equals zero. This happens when $x = -4,\;\text{OR} \;x=2$.

What is the value of the numerator at each of those values?

- Not zero.

So we can conclude there is a are vertical asymptote at each of the two values of $x$ for which the rational function is not defined: their equations are given simply by $x = -4$ and $x = 2$. These "zeros" are the points at which the function intersects the $x$-axis.

Suggestion: Graphing the function helps build intuition, or when you're completely stuck; doing so also helps one to draw the graph, and/or to confirm your analysis.

Note: The zeros in the numerator are *non-problematic*: having factored the numerator, we can see that that $f(x) = 0 \iff x = 0 \;\text{OR}\; x = 6$.

Comment: So I'm going to find the answer by doing the bottom of the function.  Which the answers are going to be -4 and 2. Are you also saying that I don't do anything at the top of the function??

Comment: $f(x)$ is ONE function, with a numerator $g(x)$ and a denominator $h(x)$. When the numerator g(x) equals zero, the denominator h(x) does not, and we know $\dfrac 0{h(x)} = 0$. Hence, no problems.

Comment: @amWhy: Very helpful suggestions! +1